# Wordpress post recommendation system using Python

Tags: python, php, wordpress, recommendation-engine

Using Wordpress and Python I am trying to develop a post recommendation system that looks at following information:

- Additional user profile data that includes job type, interests, age and gender
- Previously read posts by the user Posts that have high view count by other similar users
- Posts that have high rating by other users with similar interests

And using algorithms in Python matches that data and recommends other posts that would be of interest to that specific user.

Is this possible? How can I get Python to 'talk' to Wordpress via PHP?

Any advice would be most appreciated - there seems to be no-one on google who is looking to build a wordpress post recommendation system.

Comment: It's a huge topic to discuss here. I would not recommend executing python code from PHP or vice-versa. Better if you have some scheduled script (also written in Python) that populates a DB with recommendations: doing it live could be very expansive (computationally wise).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress `Rest API` to implement this connection between python and PHP. **developer.wordpress.org** docs can help you using the word press rest api to commiunicate with the core.
[Wordpress Rest API Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)